# UITableView resize image on background thread in self sizing Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uitableview, resize

I have implemented a cell that is self sizing based on the intrinsic content size of the image. The images should all have the same width and therefore I have to resize them. I notice that the scrollview does not scroll that smooth anymore. I tried to perform the resizing on a background thread but synchronous so the resulting images can determine the cell height. I tried:

```
     __block __weak id weakCell = cell;
__block __weak id weakSelf = self;
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){

 UIImage *resizedImage = [weakSelf imageWithImage:currentOrderdItem.shoppingCartImage scaledToWidth:228 * npx] ;
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [weakCell updateProductImage:resizedImage];
    });
});
```

in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, but it never completes.

How can I resize an image on the background thread and return use the result to size my self-sizing cell ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `dispatch_async`. Use below line of code:

```
__block __weak id weakCell = cell;
__block __weak id weakSelf = self;
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^ (void) {
UIImage * resizedImage = [weakSelf imageWithImage: currentOrderdItem.shoppingCartImage scaledToWidth: 228 * npx];
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ (void) {
    [weakCell updateProductImage: resizedImage];
});
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: You should retrieve the cell again within the dispatch block via `tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath` in case it might not be the same cell as `weakCell` especially if user scrolls too fast.

Comment: @ozgur Can I just use the index inside of the completion block or do I have to assign it to the dispatch blocks in some way to make sure it does not change when the user scrolls fast?

Comment: This does not work well. Because the call is asynchronous the cellForRowAtIndexPath method may return before the image was resized. That means that the cell is not sized correctly, beause the height is based on the image;s dimensions. I tried calling layoutIfNeeded in the completion block but this does not change the height of the already visible cell.